# Changing text between spans using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got this block of HTML:

```
<div class='translate' id='community_participation'>
Supported by
<span class='notranslate'>
52
</span>
customers like
you, as well as
<a href="/gsfnmichelle/people">the <span class='notranslate'>GSFNMICHELLE</span> team</a>.
</div>
```

I know I can change the whole thing with `$('#community_participation.translate').html('Something here.');`

But I don't know how to change the text between spans, namely "Supported by," "customers like you, as well as," "the," and "team."

Comment: Open your HTML file, and make the necessary edits. If you have text that you want to update programmatically, wrap it in an element so that you can target it later. jQuery doesn't do well at specifically targeting text nodes. The [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) and [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) methods (as you point out) allow you to edit the entire text content, and the [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) method will select text nodes as well, but specifically targeting them isn't supported afaik

Comment: I don't have access to the full HTML. That's why I asked how to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use jQuery [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the text node and [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) it inside new element for easier to manage:

```
var el = $('.translate').contents().filter(function() {
             return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
         }).eq(0).wrap('<span class="newDiv"></span>');
```

Then you can change text using [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('span.newDiv').text('New Text');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FpuX9/)**

Answer (score 1):

To change the text "Supported by", for example, you would look at the first textNode in the markup (using index 0)

```
$(function() {
    $('#community_participation').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    })[0].textContent = "Support comes from";
});
```

Output:
Support comes from 52 people just like you, as well as the GSFNMICHELLE team.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
num_customers = jQuery('#community_participation').text().split('\n')[3];

jQuery('#community_participation').html('Supported by ' + num_customers + ' community members, as well as <a href=/teded/people>the GSFNMICHELLE team</a>');
```

Hurray!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.notranslate').html('your text');
```

Comment: No, they can't; the text they want is **not** inside those elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't wrap the section you want to change in spans, than you could probably just use replace.
example:

```
$('a.question-hyperlink').html($('a.question-hyperlink').html().replace('Changing','Something else'))
```